# Passing actions to the next button

Tags: java, android, performance

I have 5 buttons. 
The current button, button 1 is flashing. The others are inactive. Once the user clicks button 1, the animation on button 1 stops, and button 2 becomes active and flashes.
The problem...The first button flashes, but it doesn't jump to button 2. Is my case statement setup wrong?
Here is what I've got so far...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private int activeButton =1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_one);

    //setting up the buttons
    Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    Button Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    Button Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    Button Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    Button Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);

    //method to switch between buttons
    buttonClickHandler(Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5);
}

private void buttonClickHandler(Button a, Button b, Button c, Button d, Button e){

    switch(activeButton++){
        case 1:
            //method to make the button animate etc
            makeButtonActive(a);
            break;
        case 2:

            makeButtonActive(b);
            break;
        case 3:

            makeButtonActive(c);
            break;
        case 4:

            makeButtonActive(d);
            break;
        case 5:

            makeButtonActive(e);
            break;
    }
}

private void makeButtonActive(Button bu){
    //setting up the animation
    Animation mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    mAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    bu.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //providing the after click stuff
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
            v.setFocusable(false);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because the method which starts the animation is called only once. It needs to be called when the other button is clicked.

Call this

```
buttonClickHandler(Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5);
```

in `onClick()` and define all the buttons at class level

**EDIT**

```
private int activeButton =1;
Button Button1;
Button Button2;
Button Button3;
Button Button4;
Button Button5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_one);

    //setting up the buttons
    Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_5);
    buttonClickHandler(Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5);
}

private void buttonClickHandler(Button a, Button b, Button c, Button d, Button e){ 
    switch(activeButton++){
        case 1:
            //method to make the button animate etc
            makeButtonActive(a);
            break;
        case 2:
            makeButtonActive(b);
            break;
        case 3:
            makeButtonActive(c);
            break;
        case 4:
            makeButtonActive(d);
            break;
        case 5:
            makeButtonActive(e);
            break;
    }
}

private void makeButtonActive(Button bu){
    //setting up the animation
    Animation mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    mAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    bu.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //providing the after click stuff
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
            v.setFocusable(false);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setEnabled(false);
            buttonClickHandler(Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** You shouldn't start variable names with capital letters

Comment: so the makeButtonActive method is no longer a standalone method but is in the onCreate?

Comment: Yes it would be in `onCreate`, otherwise first animation won't work